# Can Entity Framework Core return view model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a situation which can be explained by below analogy.

**Example:** let's say we have 3 tables `Categories` => `SubCategories` => `Products`.

1 category can have many subcategories and 1 subcategory can have many products.

I am showing simple card for products details with category and subcategory names but for it I am writing the EF like.

```
var products = await _context.Products
                             .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                             .Include(x => x.SubCategory)
                             .Include(x => x.SubCategory.Category).ToListAsync()
```

The SQL generated is too expensive.

When the products are reached to the controller then Automapper starts it's magic to map according to my required view model.

I am new to Entity Framework Core and I have three questions:

1. Is it there a better way to write above code?
2. Can I return a view model directly from Entity Framework Core? In the above case, can I return a model with properties showing just names of Products, SubCategory and Category?
3. If I can't return, then how can I convince myself to stop using Dapper?

Comment: Use `ProjectTo` instead. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. You can use the `ThenInclude` operation to make the code easier to read.

```cs
var products = await _context.Products.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                                       .Include(x => x.SubCategory)
                                       .ThenInclude(x => x.Category).ToListAsync()
```

2. Yes or no. It depends on what your `ViewModel` is.

Entity framework is a framework for operating database entities. But `ViewModel` is a concept in MVVM. It was two different concepts and have no relationship.

Usually, the view is rendering what is needed to be rendered. So we return it a `ViewModel` instead of `Entity`. If the `Entity` itself is what you need to be rendered, just return it! It's ok.

```cs
return View(viewName: "myview", model: products);
```

```cs
@model IEnumerable<Product> // Product is your entity in EF. You can use it in a view.
```

It's fine.

But, consider what the view needs is not what you got from entit-framework. Now you need to convert the entity to the `ViewModel`. For example:

```
var entity = await dbContext.MyTable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
var viewModel = new MyViewModel
{
    Color = entity.Color // Only need to return the color, for example.
}
return View(viewModel);
```

```
@model MyViewModel

<h2>The color of it is @Model.Color</h2>
@*You can't access other properties of the entity here in the view.*@
```

And the other properties will not be returned to the view.

And some tools like `AutoMapper` can just help you do the map job.

Another way is to use `Select()` to return the column on your choice. For example:

Entity definition and view model definition.

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Don't want to return this.
    public string Name { get; set; } // Only want to return this.
}

public class ProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var products = _context.Products; // While the products is declared, the query was not happened in the database. It only defines an IQueryable object.
List<ProductDto> viewModel = await products.Select(t => new ProductDto
{
    Name = t.Name // Manually map here.
})
.ToListAsync();

return View(viewModel);
```

In your view:

```
@model List<ProductDto>
foreach (var dto in Model)
{
  <h2>dto.Name</h2>
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by easy to read. Will there be a difference in sql generated in case of theninclude??

Comment: The sql generated is the same. But using `ThenInclude` is a best practice. To get better performance, consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837585/entity-framework-6-query-performance/59837819#59837819

Comment: Above is just an example i have relationship with atleast 7 different entities. To rephrase my question can i return column of my choice( which icalled view model) by using something like rawsql etc

Comment: Of course. I am editting this answer and will tell you how to return columns on your choice.

Comment: As for raw sql query, consider reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: I already read those links but the limitation is it returns an entity. in above case product. I can't select different columns from different entities. Hope you understand my problem

Comment: Isn't the `Select()` operation what you need?

Comment: Can i use the include and then include inside the Select ?? i guess i can't. If i can't write then it is of no use.. i want to involve other tables only when the details are filtered out. Currently the generated sql brings all the columns of al the included tables to the database and then maps. it's too expensive and problamatic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206647/discussion-between-anduin-and-tiger).

Answer (score 2):

Automapper can generate the sql for you, basically doing the mapping to your viewmodel/DTO in the database.

Use the `ProjectTo` extension to `IQueryable`, explained [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html).